# Cakephp querying Model by strict associated data

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, models, cakephp-2.2

I have a model X which is associated with Model Y.
X hasMany Y.
Y has an attribute "status".
I want to find all X such that the status of ALL Ys associated to X is equal to "active", i.e all Y.status =="active".

Here's a simplified schema:

### X

### id....name

0.....test
1.....two

### Y

### id....status....x_id

0.....active.....0
1.....inactive..0
2.....active....1
3.....active....1

I Want my query to return x with the ID 1, since both its associated Y records are active. I don't want it to return x with ID 0 since both its Y records aren't active.

I have tried using join queries, but they keep returning the unexpected result by returning both X.
I'm using Cakephp 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = TableRegistry::get('Y')->find()->where(['x_id' => 1);

//with assosiation
$data = TableRegistry::get('Y')->find()->where(['x_id' => 1])->contain(['X']);
```

full documentation here http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

**EDIT**

to search by status you can add search parameter in where()

```
$data = TableRegistry::get('Y')
                ->find()
                ->where(['x_id' => 1, 'status' => 'active'])
                ->contain(['X']);
```

Using CakePHP 2.x

```
$data = $this->Y->find('all',
        array(
            'conditions'=>array('x_id'=>1,'status'=>'active'),
            'contain' => array('X')
        ));
```

Comment: I'm using cakephp 2.2. Is there a way in it?

Also, I want to query by "status" of Y.

Comment: Do you know of doing this in CakePhp 2.0 ?
The query should not include the ID. It should be returned in a manner that if X has all Ys with status "active", it should return. In the example, only x with id=1 had all Ys with "active" status.
I shouldn't need to explicitly tell that I need x.id = 1.

Comment: But this doesn't solve it.
Can you please look into the problem again?
I want all Xs such that the status of ALL Ys associated with it is "active"

Comment: you can add contain parameter

Comment: That doesn't work. I want ONLY those Xs with which all Ys have an active status.
I think a NOT IN (where Y has other than active status) query would do.

Comment: then remove 'x_id' => 1

Comment: That doesn't work in helping achieve the exact result. It brings back all Xs where even one Y is active.